# How I can use an external variable in a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to use a **lambda** expression in a forEach loop to concatenate to a variable "i" a string that is evaluated for each object.

here is the code

```
private String getStringActiveRooms(@NotNull ArrayList<Chat_room> c){
    String i;
    c.forEach( (chat_room) -> i = i.concat(chat_room.getName() + "[" + chat_room.activeUsers() + "/" + chat_room.maxUsers() + "]" + ", "));

    return i;

}
```

It throws me an error because external variables must be **final** to be used in a lambda expression.

But if I make final the variable I can't **change** it and the code didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Make it a field of the class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: Why not map over each object in `c` and create a new arraylist and then join all the values together? [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523935/selecting-objects-from-an-arraylist-based-on-value-of-certain-fields)

Comment: Do [these questions answer your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+lambda+use+outside+variable+site:stackoverflow.com)? What searching have you done prior to asking this question?

Comment: Streams would be great for this.

Comment: first I was using a for loop but now I know lambda and I tried a new form

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen are them more efficient?

Comment: I found solution making it the first elemento of a final array

Comment: They are fine for your purpose. The heavy operations here are the string manipulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StringBuffer`

```
private String getStringActiveRooms(@NotNull ArrayList<Chat_room> c){
    final StringBuffer i = new StringBuffer();
    c.forEach( (chat_room) -> i.append(chat_room.getName() + "[" + chat_room.activeUsers() + "/" + chat_room.maxUsers() + "]" + ", "));

    return i.toString();

}
```

In addition you have to know that using `StringBuffer` is better from a performance point of view: **String are immutable** this means that if you have a String `i` every iteration  `i + "something"` creates a new String object in the heap space allocating memory for a temporary variable